# What are the different ways that a player character can create difficult terrain?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation, terrain

I'm playing around with a character concept (D&D 5e) based around a sort of support build that combines the sentinel feat with difficult terrain to trap monsters that are trying to get to the friendly, and very squishy, casters in my party.
At the moment, I'm looking for any and all different ways that a PC can create difficult terrain. I'm still early in the process, so I'm willing to consider any class/subclass combination.

Comment: I don't recall Sentinel and difficult terrain interacting directly. I imagine your strategy is to put the difficult terrain to your side with 5' separating you, so that an enemy passing you is either close enough for an OA or going through the difficult terrain?

Comment: You may also want to consider spells that create disincentives to walk on a square, eg using Create Bonfire which will burn enemies who stand on the square with the fire.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is just asking for a list and as new content comes out this is going to become obsolete.

Comment: @SeriousBri We have nearly countless similar questions and they remain open. I am voting to leave this open

Comment: Yep, there is nothing unusual about this question type here, and in this case, the desired effect is clearly defined and well-scoped.

Comment: Bounded list question usually fit.  This one seems to.

Answer (score 6):

### Spells

- [Mold Earth](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/mold-earth) - A cantrip, probably the easiest way to make difficult terrain but it's only 5ft at a time.
- [Arcane Hand](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/arcane-hand)
- [Black Tentacles](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/black-tentacles)
- [Blade Barrier](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/blade-barrier)
- [Bones of Earth](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/bones-of-the-earth)
- [Earth Tremor](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/earth-tremor)
- [Earthquake](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/earthquake)
- [Entangle](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/entangle)
- [Erupting Earth](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/erupting-earth)
- [Grease](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/grease?page=2)
- [Ice Storm](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/ice-storm)
- [Insect Plague](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/insect-plague)
- [Investiture of Ice](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/investiture-of-ice)
- [Mirage Arcane](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/mirage-arcane)
- [Maelstrom](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/maelstrom)
- [Sleet Storm](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/sleet-storm)
- [Spike Growth](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/spike-growth)
- [Storm Sphere](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/storm-sphere)
- [Storm of Vengence](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/Storm-of-Vengeance)
- [Wall of Water](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/wall-of-water)
- [Warding Wind](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/warding-wind)
- [Web](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/web?page=2)

Some monsters can create difficult terrain. You could polymorph yourself or someone else into a monster, though I think this is a terrible strategy.

- [Gibbering Mouther](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/gibbering-mouther)